# Forward rates diffusion

Tags: black-scholes, interest-rates, forward

I used a simple market model (Black 76)  to price an american swaption.

It's a formula similar to B&S, with another numeraire and forward rate as underlying.

I used the SDE:  $$ dF = \sigma * F dW $$

Now I want to price a contract wich is the sum of 4 swaptions with different Tenors, so I have to simulate 4 forward rates.

Should I take into account the correlation between the forward rate or can I simply simulate the rates independently ?

Comment: @Imorin why would you need to simulate at all - Black's formula offers a closed form solution !! for swaption prices

Comment: Thus the price of your contract would just be the sum of the four swaption prices calculated via Black's formula. You might need to get different vols in case of different maturities.

Comment: I use simulation to price an american swaption

Comment: do use finite differences or monte-carlo least squares or a tree ?

Comment: you should perhaps complement you question by mentioning that you are pricing american-style swaption. Otherwise most people we react as I did

Comment: Simple Monte-Carlo to build the exercise boundary.

Comment: Im quite confused how do you build an exercise boundary with simple monte carlo ?  you would end up with embedded stochastic. Could you perhaps decribe what you are doing concretly ?

Comment: I use this method: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~s0237075/projectm3s/projectm3s.pdf

Comment: I know this may not be the best method. Would you answer my question about the forward rates correlation ?

Comment: I will but I first had to understand what you are actually doing. Now that I have a more or less accurate picture I will be able to answer you. However the answer isn't as trivial or easy as it seems. Also note that you can't really simulate several forward rates as log-normal under the same measure. As I see it you are using the T-forward-dynamics ?

Comment: yes.... can I add the prices ? If fel like it would be okay beacuse the Expectation is linear, but I think the filtration $F_t$ won't be the same.

Comment: This question is confused, if you are using Black to price a swaption, the rate you are simulating is the *swap* rate not the forward rate. If you want to price something which is the sum of four swaption of different tenors, you will be simulating four different *swap* rates. If you are okay with the inherent inconsistency of this whole approach,  the short answer is Yes,  you need to have correlated diffusions, because the sum of lognormals is not lognormal, despite the "linearity" of your contract.

Answer (score 1):

The filtration is hardly the problem.

Let's say you want to price a 1x4 and a 2x3 years swaption. Thus you model three forward rates $L(t,T_1,T_2), L(t,T_2, T_3),  L(t,T_3,T_4)$

The swaprate $S_{\alpha,\beta}(t)$ depends on the forward rates $L_i(t,T_{i-1},T_i)$ with $i \in (\alpha+1, \dots, \beta)$

Thus the price of the 1x4 swaption given by $P(0,T_1)E^1[(S_{1,4}(T_1)-K)^+]$. Under the $Q^1$ measure only one rate can have the log-normal dynamics !! **Thus you can't just model the three forward rates as log-normal !!!!**

What you can do however is to directly model the swap rates $S_{1,4}, S_{2,4}$. You can assume log-normal dynamics for both and simulate them with whatever correlation structure you think is plausible. In this case you can also just add the expectations.

Whether you model the rates as correlated or not depends on your market data !! Obviously the correlation structure will have an effect on the price.

Comment: I may have mixed L and S...

Comment: I don't understand why there is a difference between modelling S and L. Why Under the Q1 measure only one (forward ?) rate can have the log-normal dynamics ?

Comment: the swap rate is different quantity than the forward rate (but they coincide in case of a one period swap) Perhaps this can help: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.410.625&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: The difference is clear now, but not the reason why $S_{i,j}$ could all be log normal but not the $L_{i,j}$

Comment: both can - but with the $S_ij$ each swap-rate could be modelled as being log normal. You can however model only one forward rate as log normal if you want to price swaption by simulating forward rates